# Codeigniter - How to show custom error code

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

My problem is sounds quiet trivial but yet I've found no solution, not even here. I want to show custom error with custom code on Codeigniter4. So I did this

```
show_error('there is an error !', '600');
```

But I get this

> Call to undefined function App\Controllers\show_error()

I assumed that I can directly use it like shown in the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/errors.html) (Please Codeigniter team, write the docs properly) as it says nothing about which `use` need to be included.

Comment: where exactly you're using the method?

Comment: @OMiShah in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Codeigniter 4, `show_error` function is not available as a global function like in previous version. You should make a custom class for handling custom errors.

Something like:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use CodeIgniter\Exceptions\Exception;

class CustomException extends Exception
{
    protected $code = 600;
    protected $message = 'There is an error!';
}
```

Then use `throw new \App\Exceptions\CustomException();` wherever you wanted to trigger this custom error.